# No data at all is showing in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

I have created numerous `Xcode` projects to see if this was a single project problem but no. The problem that I am getting is that when I populate a `UITableVIiew` with either local data or data that is stored in a Parse database it does not show.

I have tried re-installing Xcode, cleaning my project and walking through the code/project to see if I'd made a mistake but everything looks in place.

An example is that I created a `UITableViewController` with a `UIImage` in the cell and when I build and run the project it does not show up.

Here is an example: 
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You tagged this question Swift. Please update your question with your relevant Swift code.

Comment: @rmaddy. My mistake there is no code. All of the above is storyboard based

Comment: I was thinking this could be a bug with Xcode but I am surprised that it was not fixed when I removed Xcode and re-installed it. Has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: Have you added constraints? In the debug view heirarchy, is the `UIImageView` being created?

Comment: @Rikh Thanks for commenting. Sadly, no it is not being created :(

Comment: @Rikh also, yes I have constraints

Comment: Please post your code that loads data to tableview

Comment: @MidhunMP you want me to post code that has been created by Xcode when I created my Table View Controller. Is that relevant?

Comment: @TimSmith: Xcode won't write code for what you need. It just adds stub methods/default methods. You need to write code to load your data and display it in your tableview. (If you don't want to write code, just make your tableview static)

Comment: @MidhunMP I have a UIImage in my table view cell, from previous I should not need to write any code for that to show up when I build and run my project. Correct?

Comment: @TimSmith What is the value you(Xcode code) returning from numberOfRowsInASection method ?

Comment: Please edit you question with autogenerated code.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement two required methods of `UITableViewDataSource`.

Something like that:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 5;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I have a Swift coca class for my table view already created with the above methods

Comment: You said in your comments above that there was no code.  Now you're saying there is.  If there's code then edit your question and post it.

Comment: @Frankie Only code created by Xcode when I created a Swift file. I personally haven't had the chance to write any code yet until I fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

This would go quicker if you just posted the available code...  Annnnyway...

The reason I ask is because if you've only done this in storyboard, and it's a dynamic table, the table looks to your `numberOfRowsInSection` method to see if it should be populating the table or not.  If this is 0, then you'll get no rows no matter what you put into the storyboard.

Also, if you've got a cell identifier of `cell` in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, but you haven't identified your storyboard cell as `cell`, then you'll still get blank cells.

Furthermore, if you have implemented these two methods correctly, you need to ensure that this table is hooked up to that class as it's dataSource, either via storyboard or programatically.

But these are all just guesses because I would need to see code to figure it out.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer and help. I have added the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in my question, but if you would like to see the full code here is a link to my project - https://www.dropbox.com/s/etcp5hz6uxkeqo3/Iconic.zip?dl=0

Comment: @TimSmith: I've checked your project and it's working fine. It is loading the image in cell, but taking a few seconds to load (It depends on network speed). The default image is not loading because you are asking parse to load it's actual content immediately after cellForRow method is called (If you comment out cell1.cellImageNailView?.file = imageFile
        cell1.cellImageNailView.loadInBackground() you can see your images immediately)

Comment: @MidhunMP I updated to Xcode 8.1 last night and tested my project on the iPhone 7 simulator and it did not work, so I tried it on my iPhone 6s and it worked! I did not have to change any code. I think this may have been some sort of bug? Thanks for the help  much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `UITableViewController`, have you changed the cells to static?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You said you don't have any custom code other than what Xcode provides. That is your problem.

You need to implement the UITableViewDataSource methods in order to install your data into your table view. Xcode does not do that.  The code Xcode puts into your view controller tells the table view that there is no data. You need to report that there is at least 1 section, and at least 1 row in that section. You then need to write code for `cellForRowAtIndexPath` that installs data from your model into your cells.

Nikita lists 2 of the 3 methods that you must implement before you table view will do anything.